# Comic Identification: When did Hulk have a beard?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, the-incredible-hulk

I'm not sure if this is even real or not - a friend just posted it on facebook. He's not a comic reader though, just liked the image I guess.

Anyone know if this is from an actual story arc and which one? I've never seen Hulk depicted like this with a beard. Even in Old Man Logan he didn't look this way. Could very well just be fanart but thought I'd ask.

[image]

Comment: Also that’s Spider-Man 2099, but not Hulk 2099 (I don’t think).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There was a bearded Hulk, called the [*Maestro*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maestro_(comics)) in the mini-series The Incredible Hulk: Future Imperfect #1-2 (Dec 1992 - Jan 1993)

> The Maestro largely possesses the same powers as the Hulk, but to a greater degree than most incarnations due to the century's worth of radiation he has absorbed as a result of the nuclear wars that decimated his Earth (the present Hulk speculated that his insanity might also contribute to his greater strength).

[image]

It seems that maestro fought Spider-man in two numbers **Captain Marvel Vol 3 #29** / **The Incredible Hulk #457:**

> Captain Marvel Vol 3 #29: Captain Marvel and Spider-Man from 2099 travel in time and land in a large castle. (*Maestro's* castle)
>
> The Incredible Hulk #457: The Maestro starts to battle Captain Marvel and Spider-Man 2099.

Follow the link to learn more [about these battles](http://www.incrediblehulkonline.com/themaestro.html).

It seems that the picture of you post will be the cover of [Spider-Man 2099 #9’s February 2015 release.](http://whateveraspidercan.com/2014/11/22/spider-man-2099-meet-maestro-future-imperfect/)

Comment: Thanks I'll look into tracking this down. Do you know if the art I posted is from this storyline?

Comment: I think it is the cover of one number: Spider-Man 2099 #9’s release, aimed for February 2015. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: If you look closely at the beard in the photo, you can see the gold disks that are also in the possible fanart.

Comment: And is that Mjölnir he's wielding? Interesting.

Comment: Maestro also appears in Secret War, where he commands a country of Hulks, in another Spinoff I can't remember the name right now, where he outwits the Collector, Old Man Logan (really Maestro, not the Hulk of the Wastelands), where he tries to start a nuclear war, and in the Hulk series before Secret War, where he was depicted as a possible future version of Doc Green.

Answer (score 6):

That image, according to a [reverse Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1022&bih=629&tbs=sbi:AMhZZiv9aGo0fKfw7Fe8lYaAPMPfNgLYrEAnO--rOzyk0YlE9HdmJ9Gjze_1vMQT0FMdQjethkAvDNFGuHWgdy67zwkBgYOTVfajFwE4MxfKYcurlHd822kXHiqQUxmkJbKYaYH0qnKlytaTEScHFNFHK_1KGBuLygdVG4lC8oN3pwh4dl36RYBz2-e7S8e591CgEck9rhxUy3ovrDdlDpK17FxRtpIpYEOP3LiixojxEbShRYeg0Q7quIvZm9jKZtFKyWtd2VUw4eu-Q95YjnSzE71WV_1oBXe9Ng55qRnBBp8aNiP1Yota092fDZ1uRBGZpaWSqBRj6YXp-eohwI0-Vv4GLh3jzklLhkXzouEST2ZtKfwNmon8tN3Ls16jdM2wnVlcTcPEsFO2SK8H8acyeVXDbaqu-Q3QXUpuBUhSspNm4sD-OE0XR4ZMPAk58fPXZKexBEpvJJW99wRm8XupS9guYeG6Ez4g10IBEQYGCWA-VnNCP-a1ufYJIhiKHVbOfGRghSt8JEkb0qecOAxUhq8PIEpcSuxDfu17D8Zx3Z66jC0viNe82vWA8GPAOnew1h1BjYa7YGwhswi-jCghZ41iYuFFSYwW6kEKN3eArRuwlnfFFYwxYpUObFYvgBr-kQmdYH-t7wTbEs7nDZFUNh-NSrPY2ngmSlHUb8VovIjFePcuyKILIbnOu3kVYE-7eO95ic8gZ89DP1XiRPUGUT0cNSKIpTMu5tCf-lvCUN20YbT8A5Jhu_1DvO4cg7vVB5GFQRDVr8enKRyFObvorFBOEbvU9evHXh7jB5raWXzEmNSdurkinbNtblj84hFnCdOabYL35nRtbkpRdhG2cKPfaEjb3uuUPyYjfwiGoYz6RyB0XLml-g9wPoWjkwrz3zV5COgYPkCkoU7lZskN5g9DzVZD_1yTaMDEMl8az7nMmOtXTZnOFzHe09uxrMlz2Iw03-nqZyBw48sIdGhp-nb3nSoUImla7WyK1plDzML8hXX5kaTALDMUf7jPrnktnTiqIA0fDLO5VfCT_1NFDe0zmbkZ6_1aKi1ZyP2ARUzk5jWIiVVF9ng3JOjsPIOFsMrgeI02kdmMl2sCBesV40d9gPy6VFUYcp4lCvC4GIKZl_1K3jlifAJ_10gCnTH_13wcSh0ZTjZKipcs9RznvpdFG_1ioSUwHI0H5mGrCcd2Uxy8SbVYVYbonuncD-hKLh_1KdGOlTNIeiJ-ANu8TV840-m3Kag6glFan7lSSN-iAirgXYagz48p7Ti7Xz2dTOYK8BFsHFdBgrfXwKOVUO_1Yb9YCJ0J-JS1cG2w12xPnRYlDYxuV5KCR6sLveMyMpfQGpHtUhFfDsOWtsvzqrHG3bIOt3UIwfgQezHJu47gyaVlHQ00kzXuBqr-gaNKREzmmhPoY4OH5sghK5plROA-fx53EFhOBV8_13Ghr7YCMPXzXwDZaDdqTc7YIr3Vk2l6UtpdRprGaU-TLdqKkI&ei=gQ6GVKHUCqu9ygOZjYLwDg&start=20&sa=N),  is associated with an upcoming issue of [Spider-Man 2099 Vol 2, issue 9](http://marvel.wikia.com/Spider-Man_2099_Vol_2_1). It's categorized as a [textless cover](http://marvel.wikia.com/Spider-Man_2099_Vol_2_9).
http://superiorspidertalk.com/spider-solicitations-for-febuary-2015-the-end-of-spider-verse/